# Can I deploy kubernetes workload that depends on a custom resource state?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to have a deployment that requires a custom resource to be ready in order to deploy. I know there is an init container approach that can watch the custom resources but it does not really fit.

Is there a way I can declare in a deployment manifest such that the deployment will not be deployed until a custom resource reach to a certain state?

Comment: Deployments in Kubernetes is _declarative_ - it is not _commands_.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail why an init container cannot be used in your case ?  This scenario seems like a good use case for it. Deployment controller doesn't have any built-in function which could observe if there are some custom resources deployed, and based on that create pods.